WiFi-driver not Found in CSL Mini PC (Ubuntu 22.04.4)
I bought a mini pc with wifi and bluetooth but no matter what I try the wifi doesn't show up. It works on windows 10 after installing the drivers, but not in ubuntu sadly.
windows drivers:
https://ftp.csl-computer.com/pub/drivers/mini-pc/CSL_Narrow_Box/51194_52233_52852/
I tried a few things, like this one:
WiFi-driver not Found in Mini PC (Ubuntu 18.04)
or
BCM43455 PCIe Wireless Adapter not recognised
Mini pc:
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Mini-PC-QuadCore-DDR3-RAM-Bluetooth/dp/B01LT46CVG
But didn't work. I have no idea. I want to use ubuntu, because of home assistant.
Any idea? I'm not a linux guru to be honest, pretty new in this.
edit: wireless log file:
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Apr 2024 16:04 CEST +0200

Booted last: 13 Apr 2024 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:    jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.5.0-27-generic #28~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 15 10:51:06 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:08a0 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Gaming mouse [Philips SPK9304]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

This system doesn't support Secure Boot

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6488064  0
mac80211             1720320  0
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
brcmutil               24576  0
cfg80211             1323008  2 wl,mac80211
wmi                    40960  1 video

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.175/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 41280sec preferred_lft 41280sec
    inet6 fd0d:3d1f:3198::82c/128 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd0d:3d1f:3198:0:ac1c:b926:537:1e54/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 602881sec preferred_lft 83990sec
    inet6 fd0d:3d1f:3198:0:e366:5056:16ca:84ce/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6fd1:96f8:2d60:10c8/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp1s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.175 metric 100

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         495       1  0 15:32 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-27-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:01:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     1. vezetékes kapcsolat
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       205b93db-b859-333e-bea0-6afef0bedff2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.175/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1713058358
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = sanyi-Narrow-Box-4K-4GB
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.175
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fd0d:3d1f:3198:0:ac1c:b926:537:1e54/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fd0d:3d1f:3198::82c/128
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fd0d:3d1f:3198:0:e366:5056:16ca:84ce/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         fe80::6fd1:96f8:2d60:10c8/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fd0d:3d1f:3198::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fd0d:3d1f:3198::/48, nh = fe80::1a34:afff:fe00:2c88, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fd0d:3d1f:3198::82c/128, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd0d:3d1f:3198::1
IP6.SEARCHES[1]:                        lan
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = lan
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd0d:3d1f:3198::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        ip6_address = fd0d:3d1f:3198::82c
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   205b93db-b859-333e-bea0-6afef0bedff2 | 1. vezetékes kapcsolat

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       6.5.0-27-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-27-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmutil
vermagic:       6.5.0-27-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-27-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   11.926484] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   14.010492] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
[   16.649536] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  560.702923] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  560.702942] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[  560.702950] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  560.702953] wl: module license taints kernel.

########## wireless info END ############


not really, sadly

sure. cant paste all them in here. https://ctxt.io/2/AADImsk8Fg

Remove the driver you installed and reboot, then in terminal ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999 post URL

I have no idea. I installed a lot of stuff because it might work, but none of them worked. I'm clueless.

Try sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source then reboot and run the other command

bash: ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999 doesn't work. no file or directory found

See the page with the wireless script link

yeah, that one works. https://ctxt.io/2/AADIbopFFQ

You didn't run the sudo apt remove command

I did and also rebooted the pc. if I run it again: sanyi@sanyi-Narrow-Box-4K-4GB:~/Asztal$ sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] sanyi jelszava:
Csomaglisták olvasása... Kész
Függőségi fa építése... Kész
Állapotinformációk olvasása... Kész
A(z) „bcmwl-kernel-source” csomag nincs telepítve, így nem lett törölve
A(z) „broadcom-sta-common” csomag nincs telepítve, így nem lett törölve
A(z) „broadcom-sta-dkms” csomag nincs telepítve, így nem lett törölve
0 frissített, 0 újonnan telepített, 0 eltávolítandó és 25 nem frissített.

sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf then reboot and run the script again

they are cannot be deleted because they are not exist it said.  sanyi@sanyi-Narrow-Box-4K-4GB:~/Asztal$ sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
rm: '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf' nem törölhető: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár
rm: 'sudo' nem törölhető: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár
rm: 'rm' nem törölhető: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár
rm: '/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf' nem törölhető: Nincs ilyen fájl vagy könyvtár
sanyi@sanyi-

any other idea? I'm starting to being hopeless

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

Remove the Broadcom drivers, then in terminal
sudo touch /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
gedit admin:///lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
Then paste the following into the file
#AP6234_NVRAM_V1.2_20140820_WIN8.1
manfid=0x2d0
prodid=0x0653
vendid=0x14e4
devid=0x4386
boardtype=0x0653
boardrev=0x1203
boardnum=22
macaddr=00:90:4c:c5:12:38
sromrev=3
#boardflags: 
# bit 19 3tswitch:   2.4GHz FEM: SP3T switch share with BT
# bit 16     nopa:   no external pa
#            keep original 0x200
boardflags=0x0090201
xtalfreq=37400
nocrc=1
ag0=255
aa2g=1
ccode=EU
pa0itssit=0x20
#PA parameters for 2.4GHz
#pa0b0=6957 default
pa0b0=6727 
pa0b1=-858
pa0b2=-178
tssifloor2g=69
# rssi params for 2.4GHz
rssismf2g=0xf
rssismc2g=0x8
rssisav2g=0x1
cckPwrOffset=3

# rssi params for 5GHz
rssismf5g=0xf
rssismc5g=0x7
#rssisav5g=0x1
rssisav5g=0x3

#PA parameters for lower a-band
#pa1lob0=5659 default
pa1lob0=5859
#pa1lob0=5659
pa1lob1=-693
pa1lob2=-178
tssifloor5gl=77

#PA parameters for midband
pa1b0=5372 
#pa1b0=5172
pa1b1=-671
pa1b2=-212
tssifloor5gm=77

#PA paramasdeters for high band
#pa1hib0=5320 default
pa1hib0=5620
#pa1hib1=-963
pa1hib1=-663
pa1hib2=-179
tssifloor5gh=74

rxpo5g=0
maxp2ga0=72
#  19.5dBm max; 18dBm target
#Per rate power back-offs for g band, in .5 dB steps. Set it once you have the right numbers.
cck2gpo=0x8888 
ofdm2gpo=0x66666666
# R54 16dBm; R48 17dBm; others 18dBm
mcs2gpo0=0xdddd
# M0~ M4 17dBm
mcs2gpo1=0xdddd
# M5M6 15dBm; M7 14.5dBm
#max power for 5G
maxp5ga0=68
# 16dBm target; 17.5dBm Max 
maxp5gla0=68
maxp5gha0=68
#Per rate power back-offs for a band, in .5 dB steps. Set it once you have the right numbers.
ofdm5gpo=0x22222222
# R54 13.5dBm
ofdm5glpo=0x22222222
ofdm5ghpo=0x22222222
mcs5gpo0=0x8888
# M0~M4 16dBm (1dB higher than ofdm)
mcs5gpo1=0x4444
# M5M6 13.5dBm; M7 12dBm
mcs5glpo0=0x4444
mcs5glpo1=0x4444
mcs5ghpo0=0x4444
mcs5ghpo1=0x4444
# Parameters for DAC2x mode and ALPF bypass
# RF SW Truth Table: ctrl0 for BT_TX; ctrl1 or 5G Tx; ctrl2 for 5G Rx; Ctrl3 for 2G Tx; Ctrl4 for 2G Rx
swctrlmap_2g=0x00080008,0x00100010,0x00080008,0x011010,0x11f
swctrlmap_5g=0x00040004,0x00020002,0x00040004,0x011010,0x2fe
gain=32
triso2g=8
triso5g=8
#tx parameters
loflag=0
iqlocalidx5g=40
dlocalidx5g=70
iqcalidx5g=50
lpbckmode5g=1 
txiqlopapu5g=0
txiqlopapu2g=0
dlorange_lowlimit=5
txalpfbyp=1
txalpfpu=1
dacrate2xen=1
papden2g=1
papden5g=1
#rx parameters
gain_settle_dly_2g=4
gain_settle_dly_5g=4
noise_cal_po_2g=-1
noise_cal_po_40_2g=-1
noise_cal_high_gain_2g=73
noise_cal_nf_substract_val_2g=346
noise_cal_po_5g=-1
noise_cal_po_40_5g=-1
noise_cal_high_gain_5g=73
noise_cal_nf_substract_val_5g=346
cckpapden=0
# Enable OOB interrupt: level trigger
#muxenab=0x10
# Out-of-band GPIO wakeup
sd_gpout=4
sd_gpval=1
sd_gpdc=0
btc_flags=71
btc_params8=15000
btc_params22=8000
btc_params83=9000
btc_params84=4500
rssicorrnorm=15
Save, exit editor, reboot
The device you have is sdio and it needs this firmware file, luckily it was in the link to the Windows driver, so it just needed to be saved to the right location for the wifi to work
